# Getting table values plus count of some columns in the same linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

Hi guys i am using a Dto Class object like the following

```
    public class TypeDTO{

       public long Type { get; set; }

       public string Name { get; set; }

       public byte DefType { get; set; }

       public byte DefCode { get; set; }

       public Dictionary<int,decimal> SumOfEachType = new Dictionary<int,decimal>();
      }
```

and in my repository-class  where i return an `IEnumerable<TypeDTO>` i try to construct a linq query where except from getting the whole table and assign each record in the appropriate property and try to create also a dictionary  like

```
          dictionary<typeColumn,Count(typecolumn)>
```

to be specific

```
       var Types = _db
            .table
            .Select(ds => new TypeDTO()
            {
                Type = long.Parse(ds.RIT_TYPE.ToString()),
                Name = ds.RIT_NAME,
                DefType = byte.Parse(ds.RIT_DEF_TYPE.ToString()),
                DefCode = byte.Parse(ds.RIT_DEF_CODE.ToString()),
               SumOfEachType = new Dictionary ????? 
            });
```

In the SumOfEachType  property i want to save the results of an sql query like the following

```
      SELECT rit_type,count(rit_type) as sum
      FROM table group by rit_type
```

Possible ways to go so far:

1)Create 2 linq statements .Following that way i am not sure how to combine the results in one typeDTO object

2)Using one linq query and when its  time for SumOfEachType to get a value in some unkown to me so far way i include a second linq statement to get the count and the **rit_type** column

thanks

Comment: Why put summary by each type into each separate object? Use two separate queries for that and two separate dtos

Comment: Could you construct your query such that you can use `.ToDictionary(ds => ds.ItemAsKey, ds => ds.ItemAsValue)`?

Comment: Karl i suppose you mean that one linq will include the .ToDictionary and then  as  i  said above i 'll try to combine the 2 linqs results to one return ienumerable?That is the problem i dont know how :)

Answer (score 0):

So given the following database model and dto:

```
public class DatabaseModel
{
    public int RIT_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string RIT_NAME { get; set; }
    public int RIT_DEF_TYPE { get; set; }
    public int RIT_DEF_CODE { get; set; }
}

public class TypeDTO
{
    public long Type { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public byte DefType { get; set; }

    public byte DefCode { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<int, int> SumOfEachType = new Dictionary<int, int>();
}
```

I change the dictionary to `Dictionary<int, int>` - if your intent is to simply get a count then there's no need for decimal - unless you have some other requirement in which case you can just refactor to fit you needs:

Then with the following in memory object:

```
var databaseModels = new List<DatabaseModel>
        {
            new DatabaseModel
            {
                RIT_TYPE = 1,
                RIT_NAME = "Test1",
                RIT_DEF_TYPE = 1,
                RIT_DEF_CODE = 1
            },
            new DatabaseModel
            {
                RIT_TYPE = 2,
                RIT_NAME = "Test2",
                RIT_DEF_TYPE = 2,
                RIT_DEF_CODE = 2
            },
            new DatabaseModel
            {
                RIT_TYPE = 3,
                RIT_NAME = "Test3",
                RIT_DEF_TYPE = 3,
                RIT_DEF_CODE = 3
            }
        };
```

Your query would look like the following:

```
        var datebaseModelDictionary = databaseModels
            .GroupBy(model => model.RIT_TYPE)
            .ToDictionary(models => models.Key, models => models.Count());

        var result = databaseModels
            .Select(model => new TypeDTO
            {
            Type = long.Parse(model.RIT_TYPE.ToString()),
            Name = model.RIT_NAME,
            DefType = byte.Parse(model.RIT_DEF_TYPE.ToString()),
            DefCode = byte.Parse(model.RIT_DEF_CODE.ToString()),
            SumOfEachType = datebaseModelDictionary
        });
```

Comment: When i saw it i was almost sure that it was gonna work....But when i consume the data from an api controller  i get the following error .  ..Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context...Do you have any thoughts??

Comment: Sorry mate! I skimmed over and missed `_db.table` and `_db` being your context.  So I think the issue is that EF doesn't know what to do with the projected dictionary as part of the select statement.  So if you put `_db.table.AsEnumerable().Select(model => new TypeDTO` then it should work.  This means that you're pulling the entire table into memory so you must us the AsEnumerable() with caution. This is where IQueryable vs IEnumerable come into play.